# Error while adding a plugin in BlackBerry using phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins

I inserted barcode scanning plugin in cordova.jar

I followed the steps from ["BarcodeScanner plugin for Cordova"](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/BarcodeScanner)

I extracted the jar file then inserted the plugin then again make a jar using eclipse.
But I did not get the result while running the program.
I think there is problem in making a jar file.

Comment: You need to tell us what error you are getting, otherwise it is very difficult to provide help without taking a wild guess.

Comment: First i will tell you what i did.1) Extract cordva.jar file after extracting this file i am getting org folder and library.2) then i insert .java file in this path "org/apache/cordova/plugins/barcodescanner" 3) Add this statement <plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"/> 4) then i make a jar file using eclipse(using org folderand library.xml) . and replace this .jar file with new jar in ext folder.But then run this project using this command "ant blackberry build" i am getting this error

Comment: [exec] C:\Documents and Settings\nksharma.Q3TECH\Local Settings\Temp\widget
Gen.14868751551357534373934.tmp\blackberry\web\widget\autogen\WidgetConfigAutoGe
n.java:41: error: package org.apache.cordova does not exist
     [exec]         _widgetExtensions.addElement(new org.apache.cordova.CordovaE
xtension());

Comment: [exec]                                                            ^
     [exec] 1 error
     [exec] Error!: Error: java compiler failed: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_
02\bin\javac.exe @C:\DOCUME~1\NKSHAR~1.Q3T\LOCALS~1\Temp\rapc_0f851d ...
     [exec] [ERROR]                     RAPC exception occurred